# Should I only do DOM manipulation in the link fn of a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I am generally following the excellent [John Papa Angular V1](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) style guide but I'm not sure what is the best pattern to use for my following situation.

I have a directive that creates a canvas and, invokes various angular services to draw to it.

One particular section of code is very expensive, so I use two canvas buffers to draw to at various different stages.  Various sources tell me all "DOM" related stuff should be in directives.  I understood this to meean the link function only.  For now though I create two canvases in the directive controller.

Is this the best place for them? Where else would or should they go? Does it even matter? My current thinking is to create an Angular factory that creates a "canvasBuffer" that can be used in this way.  My only concern would be then managing the lifetime of that DOM object, and again it goes against the principal of only doing DOM manipulation in a directive.

```
function thingyDirectiveController($scope, canvasService, drawingService, boundsService) {
    var vm = this;

    // This may want to be moved elsewhere?
    vm.imageBufferCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    vm.imageBufferContext = vm.imageBufferCanvas.getContext('2d');

    function draw() {

        drawingService.drawBackground(vm.context);

        // Only update if required
        if (vm.videoImage.src != vm.videoFrame) {
            vm.videoImage.src = vm.videoFrame;

            // Draw image to buffer
            vm.imageBufferContext.drawImage(vm.videoImage, 0, 0, vm.videoImage.width, vm.videoImage.height);

            // etc ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you hear people mention that DOM manipulation are done in the `link` and not `controller` is because of a couple notes in the docs related to directives.

First, a note about the [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-):

> The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and can be
>   accessed by other directives

I mention this line because of what follows later under the [link description for pre-linking](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#pre-linking-function).

> Executed before the child elements are linked. Not safe to do DOM
>   transformation since the compiler linking function will fail to locate
>   the correct elements for linking.

So by putting these two notes together you can see that it is not recommended you do DOM manipulations in a controller because you may have issues with elements due to the phase the directive might be in. Therefore, best practice would be to put all DOM related functions in the link so that you don't run the risk of hitting these types of issues.